# GIF/ISF image in Xfinium.PDF PdfFlowDocument

Tags: c#, pdf, uwp, gif

I'm using the Xfinium.PDF component for UWP. I need to display an image that is encoded as GIF with ISF (here is more info: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/input-and-devices/save-and-load-ink). I have just a stream of bytes, not a physical image.

As I'm using PdfFlowDocument, I need to instantiate a PdfFlowTableImageCell.

How could I accomplish that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to convert your GIF image to PNG (or JPEG) using the BitmapDecoder/BitmapEncoder UWP classes and then create a PdfPngImage (or PdfJpegImage) that can be used in a PdfFlowTableImageCell.

UPDATE: The code below shows how to convert a GIF image to PNG in UWP (it assumes your GIF image is in a stream):

```
// Stream gifStream = your image stream
BitmapDecoder gifDecoder = 
    await BitmapDecoder.CreateAsync(gifStream.AsRandomAccessStream());
BitmapFrame gifFrame = await gifDecoder.GetFrameAsync(0);
PixelDataProvider gifPixels = await gifFrame.GetPixelDataAsync();

InMemoryRandomAccessStream pngStream = new InMemoryRandomAccessStream();
BitmapEncoder pngEncoder = 
    await BitmapEncoder.CreateAsync(BitmapEncoder.PngEncoderId, pngStream);
pngEncoder.SetPixelData(BitmapPixelFormat.Rgba8, BitmapAlphaMode.Straight, 
    gifFrame.PixelWidth, gifFrame.PixelHeight, 
    96, 96, gifPixels.DetachPixelData()); 
await pngEncoder.FlushAsync();
pngStream.Seek(0);

PdfPngImage pngImage = new PdfPngImage(pngStream.AsStream());
```

Comment: OK. Thanks Mihai. I'm trying to figure out how to convert a GIF/ISF stream (I don't have a physical file, just a stream) to a PNG stream which is required by PdfPngImage. So far, no luck.

Comment: @ata6502 I updated my answer with code showing how to convert a GIF image to PNG

Comment: Thanks Mihai. I've tried your code but it did not work as expected. The PNG image shows up on the PDF report as a black rectangle. After closer examination, it turned out that the length of the source GIF stream was 2490 bytes but the output PNG stream was only 259. I'm not sure why there is such a discrepancy. Maybe it's because the GIF has ISF info. Anyway, I'd like to send you the GIF file I'm trying to include in the PDF but I don't see any option to do that on StackOverflow.

Comment: @ata6502 please send it to our support: http://xfiniumpdf.com/xfinium-pdf-contact-us.html

Comment: Thanks Mihai. I will send it on Monday.